# Pathogen only loading some plugins

Tags: windows, vim, pathogen

I'm running gvim in Windows 10 and I'm currently running into an issue where pathogen is loading some plugins, but not others.  Specifically, I see that vimwiki is being loaded, but NOT lightline.  Both are in the same location: ~/vimfiles/bundle/

Here's the ordering of of `:scriptnames`

```
  1: ~\.vimrc
  2: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syntax.vim
  3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\synload.vim
  4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syncolor.vim
  5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\filetype.vim
  6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\menu.vim
  7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\autoload\paste.vim
  8: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftplugin.vim
  9: ~\vimfiles\colors\Monokai.vim
 10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\indent.vim
 11: ~\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim
 12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftoff.vim
 13: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1.vim
 14: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1xml.vim
 15: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\xml.vim
 16: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\plugin\lightline.vim
 17: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vimwiki\plugin\vimwiki.vim
 18: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vimwiki\autoload\vimwiki\vars.vim
 19: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vimwiki\autoload\vimwiki\u.vim
 20: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
 21: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\gzip.vim
 22: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\logiPat.vim
 23: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\manpager.vim
 24: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\matchparen.vim
 25: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
 26: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\rrhelper.vim
 27: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\spellfile.vim
 28: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
 29: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tohtml.vim
 30: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
 31: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
 32: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\autoload\lightline.vim
 33: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\autoload\lightline\tab.vim
 34: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\autoload\lightline\colorscheme\default.vim
 35: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\autoload\lightline\colorscheme\powerline.vim
 36: ~\vimfiles\bundle\lightline.vim\autoload\lightline\colorscheme.vim
 37: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\scripts.vim
 38: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\vim.vim
 39: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\python.vim
 40: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftplugin\vim.vim
 41: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\indent\vim.vim
```

What could be the issue??

Comment: But your `:scriptnames` output clearly shows that lightline (both plugin and autoload scripts) gets loaded. Now, that still doesn't mean it's active (in the way you want) if it requires configuration that you don't have done.

Comment: Thanks @IngoKarkat - I'll keep digging into it to see if I can find anything.